# CSS not overriding Bootstrap Margin tag in @media Query

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my @media query I'm trying to change the margin top(`mt-5`) assigned to a `h1` heading tag in my HTML. The other conditions work but not margin. My css sheet is linked below the bootstrap one.

I've tried adding a class to the h1, also targeting all `h1`s in that id.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/rZYXgZ)

HTML

```
<h1 class="mt-5 wcu-title">
    Why Choose Your Computer Assistant Ltd?
</h1>
```

MEDIA QUERY

```
  #showcase-wcu h1 
  {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 60%;
  }
```

Comment: i would suggest giving an ID to the h1! might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .wcu-title in the media queries seems to be overriden by the mt-5 class, the solution would be to also modify the mt-5 tag within the media queries while not modifying other elements with mt-5, the following code seems to be working.

```
    @media (max-width: 600px) {   
        .wcu-title {
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 60%;   
        }   
        h1.wcu-title.mt-5 {
            margin-top: 10px !important;   
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you remove or replace the mt-5 class. 
The mt-5 class is defined as `margin-top:3rem!important`. The fact that it's default definition includes `!important` means that even if you redefine it as 10px  in a media query using `!important`, this will not succeed as the media query will be read second.

Using a different class to the mt-5 class would appear the best option. You could alternately create a unique id that includes the mt/wcu title properties and redefine that in your media css.